# Sampling from Irwin-Hall (Uniform Sum) distribution using rejection sampling

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

Irwin-Hall Distribution is a probability distribution for a random variable defined as the sum of a number of independent random variables,each having a uniform distribution

> True or False: The greater k is (k being the k in
>   $X=\sum_{n=1}^{k}U_n$) The smaller the c you can find so that c must
>   satisfy $f(x) \leq c g(x)$ for all values of x. ($f$ being the density
>   function of the Irwin-Hall distribution).

I have a feeling its false because the more uniform random variables we sum, the bigger the variance is and then the bigger the c would need to be to bound f(x) but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: and what function is g(x)?

Comment: g is the proposal distribution density function

Comment: I guess the proposed g(x) is that is become a near (scaled) Gaussian? A quick web search shows other math.SE answers...